# Linear Function Transformations

Tags: functions, linear-transformations

I don't understand how a transformation can affect just the x variable or y variable. Since isn't y a function of x i.e. f(x) or g(x) etc. I understand that if you start with a function say f(x)=x^2 and transform it by f(x)=x^2+C then y must increase by C for the two to remain equivalent resulting in a transformation of C units in the y-axis. However could you not keep y constant (f(x) constant) and instead decrease x by a suitable amount so that x^2  has decreased enough in value  so that y= x^2+C without having to change y. However I realise that since y is a function of x decreasing the value of x must decrease the value of y which leads back to my original question how can a transformation affect only one variable. I hope this made some sense.

Comment: Your question is not so clear. But note that if you have the function $y=x^2$ and you change it to $y=x^2+c$ than for the same value of the independent variable $x$ now you have a new value of the dependent variable $y$, so, in some sense this transformation of the function change only the variable $y$ and its transformation correspond to a translation of the value of the function.
But if you perform tha transformation $x \rightarrow x+c$ your function become $y=(x+c)^2$ that is obvously different from $y=x^2+c$.

Comment: I agree that if you have the function y=x^2 and you change it to y=x^2+c than for the same value of the independent variable x now you have a new value of the dependent variable y, so, in some sense this transformation of the function change only the variable y. But equally could you not decrease the value of x so that your new x value is equivalent to the original x^2+C. In that case you could keep y the same but just decrease the value x. However y is a function of x so decreasing x would also represent a change in y resulting in a transformation in the y-axis and the x-axis.

Comment: Also I know I must be incorrect but just want to know why..

Comment: If I undestand...... for $ y=x^2+c$ you have the **same** change $+c$ of $y$ for any value of $x$, but you can not have the **same** change of $x$ that gives the old value of $y$.

Comment: let the original x be called x1 so that y=x1^2.  Then decrease x1 to a new x called x2 so that x2^2+C=x1^2. Is this not an alternative to just increasing f(x).